# Is there another way to solve the value field of a parameter of an line.

Tags: geometry, inequality, analytic-geometry, circles

Assume $P$ is a point in line $x+y=m$, where $m \in \Bbb{R}$. There are two points $A,B$ in circle $$x^2+y^2 = 10$$  such that $PA$ and $PB$ are tangent lines of the above circle. If line: $x+y=m$ has no common point with the circle: $x^2+y^2 = 10$. Find the value range of $m$.

---

Assume the center of circle is $O$, then $OBPA$ is a square. so we have $OP = \sqrt{2}\times \sqrt{10} = 2\sqrt{5}$ and $OP = \sqrt{x_*^2+y_*^2}$ (where $(x_*, y_*)$ is a point in the line $x+y=m$) and then $$|m |=|x_* + y_*| \leq \sqrt{2(x_*^2+y_*^2)}=2\sqrt{10}$$ on the other hand , because the line has no common point with the circle. so $$\frac{|m|}{\sqrt{2}} \geq \sqrt{10}$$

then we get the answer: $$2\sqrt{5} \leq m \leq 2\sqrt{10}$$ and $$-2\sqrt{10}\leq m \leq -2\sqrt{5}$$

I think my answer is right. But I feel a little unpleasant. I don't know why. I think I not really understand this problem.

---

Is there some other way to solve this problem ? thanks very much.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/557036/what-is-the-equation-for-a-line-tangent-to-a-circle-from-a-point-outside-the-cir

Comment: $|m|>\sqrt{20}$ which result in two separated intervals. $m>\sqrt{20}$ or $m<-\sqrt{20}$

Comment: @rlartiga Yes, $\sqrt{20}=2\sqrt{5}$

Comment: What I'm telling you the solution is not what you are putting https://www.wolframalpha.com/share/clip?f=d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427ek0m54nfurb

Answer (score 1):

Here is a more algebraic alternative:

If the line does not intersect the circle, then there are no common solutions between the two equations,

$$x+y = m$$
$$x^2 + y^2 = 10$$

If we manipulate the first equation, we get $y = m - x$. Substitute this into the second to get:

$$x^2 + (m - x)^2 = 10$$
$$x^2 + x^2 - 2mx + m^2 = 10$$
$$2x^2 - 2mx + m^2 - 10 = 0$$

Since there are no (real) solutions to this quadratic equation, its discriminant should be negative. In other words,

$$(-2m)^2 - 4(2)(m^2 - 10) < 0$$
$$-4m^2 + 80 < 0$$
$$m^2 > 20$$
$$|m| > \sqrt{20}$$

or if you prefer, 
$$2\sqrt{5} > m> -2\sqrt{5}$$

Comment: $m^2>20$ is $|m|>\sqrt{20}$ which result in two separated intervals. $m>\sqrt{20}$ or $m<-\sqrt{20}$

Comment: Actually the OP make the same mistake

Comment: That seems to be the case